# How can I get my lawnmower bolt off?

Tags: tools, bolts, lawn-mower

I have a Ryobi electric lawnmower, and I want to get the blade sharpened for the first time. I have a 15mm ratchet wrench, just like the instructions say, and I'm immobilizing the blade with a brick.

But no matter how hard I turn, the bolt just doesn't budge at all. I called Ryobi support, and they said the only other thing to try was spraying the bolt with WD-40. I assume the bolt is so tight because it hasn't been touched since being assembled at the factory.

I did that, let the WD-40 sit for a half hour, and tried again. The bolt still won't budge at all. What are my other options? I don't own an impact wrench.

Comment: Try cleaning the lawn masses off it and using penetrating oil.  *hint: WD-40 isn't penetrating oil*, it's water-displacing oil hence WD.  This is a common misconception which comes from WD-40's intense efforts to market their product as a do-everything oil.

Comment: @Harper Thanks! This did the trick. I bought some PB penetrating oil, let it sit, and then the bolt came off. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing for the inherent mechanical weaknesses of a ratchet wrench and the limited lever arm provided by such a short handle, consider to purchase or borrow a 15 mm box end wrench. The handle may not be much longer than the ratchet wrench, but will more safely accept a lever extension.

A strong steel pipe of a meter length or better, with an inside diameter to accept the box end wrench will give you an incredible lever arm.

If you are confident that you are turning the bolt in the correct direction and that it is designed to be removed in this manner, you are likely to free it up easily. If not, it's also possible to snap the head right off, or worse, break something internally.

Your local mower shop may also accept the mower and have the necessary tools to pull the blade. You may have to pay a bit more for the first time, but it's also likely it won't be as difficult to remove the next time.

Comment: An impact wrench will make all the difference in the world, and obviate the need to hold the blade, since the impact will land faster than the blade can turn.

Comment: A breaker bar is designed for this exact scenario where you need more torque than a little standard-size wrench is going to provide.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool I bought that attaches to the side of the mower to hold the blade in place. Not only does it to a far better job of holding the blade, it tends to fare better in torquing

[image]

The only other thing I could suggest is turn the unit on its side (be careful of the oil if it's a 4 cycle gas) and see if you can get better leverage with your wrench

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the name of the blade holder?

Comment: I just Googled "lawnmower blade holder". There's several brands

Comment: I just googled "3 inch pipe" LOL.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other very good answers already posted but here is another.

- Make sure it is not a reverse thread nut. I expect that to be the case Ryobi should know this.
- Using a socket that fits over the ratchet handle you can easily add torque by inserting a socket into the extension thus making the equivalent of a pipe extension , just in case you are as cheap as me and don't want to buy a piece of pipe.
- Get a propane torch heat the nut area up, quickly place your socket over the nut and loosen ..

Comment: Just a caution on the torch... the underside is coated with dry grass. You might set something on fire doing that

Comment: @Machavity - stating the obvious.. LOL.  of course I guess maybe if he sets it on fire he will not need to know how to loosen the nut anymore - problem solved.(Would I still get points for the Answer..) LOL